# How should I express differing daily end times for a multi-day event?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the context.

There's a seminar about retirement planning and it will be held for two days.

Day 1 ends at 2 pm next Wednesday.

Day 2 ends at 3 pm next Thursday.

Then:

> 1. The seminars will end at a different time on each day.
> 2. Each day will end at a different time.

which one would you choose and why? Is there something else that you could recommend?

P.S. The reason we use 'A' right before 'different' is because we have only two days, not more than two days, right?

Comment: Is it only a two-day event?

Comment: Seminar timings are different for both the days ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose number one, as it specifically mentions the seminars. Number two could potentially cause confusion with someone thinking that you're saying the entire day itself is ending at those times, not the seminars.

Though instead I would say:

> The seminars will end at a different time on both days.

Since there are only two days, it would sound better to use "both" rather than "each." Each would sound better for 3+ days.

You could shorten that to:

> The seminars will end at different times.

You use "a" before "different time" because time is a singular noun. Even if, for example, you had seminars over the course of five days, with each one ending at a different time, you would still say "The seminars will end at a different time on each day." The use of "a" has nothing to do with the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to address the issue of compressing the context into a neat sentence.

Please consider giving a thought to this solution:

> The first-day seminar will end one hour earlier than the other.

1. Here `the other`, as a determiner, means the second of two seminars.
2. Using comparative form of the adjective `ealier` to differ the ending times makes the notification more specifical.

As said in your question, we need to express differing daily end times for a multi-day event. In this case, I'd like to recommend this:

> Each seminar has a different end time.

1. The following sentence exemplifies the use of `each` and `both`:

   > Both sisters are living.
   >   Each dislikes the other.
   >   Both have candybars, but each prefers her own.

   So we use `each` here to mean every one of two or more people or things, seen separately.
2. An example of `each has a different` from [thegoodgrammarcompany](http://thegoodgrammarcompany.com/blog/education-be/):

   > I ask two questions because, sadly, each has a different answer.